# What are the known natural biochemical reasons for a dead human's body not fully decaying?

Tags: decay

What are the known natural biochemical reasons for a dead human's body not fully decaying (decomposing)?

EDIT:
I am interested in a scientific explanation of those cases, in which human body would not fully decay, for example, some parts of skin and hair would still be there, and I am not talking about such cases like hand-made mummification (like, say, those Pharaoh's mummies in Egypt).

Comment: Please clarify your question a bit. Are you asking under what circumstances a body might not decay, and the biochemical reasons thereof? Or do you have a specific circumstance in mind?

Comment: @jarlemag - "Please clarify your question a bit" - Sure. I am interested in a scientific explanation of those cases, in which human body would not fully decay, for example, some parts of skin and hair would still be there, and I am not talking about such cases like hand-made mummification (like, say, those Pharaoh's mummies in Egypt).

Comment: @brillant You can edit your question to add your clarifications. Additionally you should add some research you already did. For example try checking about a relation of humidity and temperature to decay.

Comment: related posts- [1](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/11266/humidity-for-wood-rotting) and [2](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/13412/bodys-decomposition)

Comment: @brilliant are you talking about bodies preserved in bogs and ice.

Comment: @potterbond007: "are you talking about bodies preserved in bogs and ice" - Not really. I'm talking about those cases when a body in a coffin for some reason is not fully decomposed while all the surrounding natural conditions apparently should bring it the state of full decomposition (except, perhaps, for the bones).

Comment: question requires case study reference and clarification!